# Why do the mouseenter/mouseleave events fire when entering/leaving child elements in an SVG?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, d3.js, mouseenter

I have an SVG, inside which there are more SVGs with a variable number of rect elements inside them, all generated from a data object. Here's the general hierarchy:

```xml
<svg class="parent-svg">
    <svg class="child-svg">
        <rect />
        <rect />
    </svg>
    <svg class="child-svg">
        <rect />
        <rect />
    </svg>
</svg>
```

I've bound mouseenter/mouseleave events to the `.child-svg` elements, but I'm finding that the events are firing when my mouse goes to the whitespace in between the `<rect>` elements. My understanding of mouseenter/mouseleave is that they shouldn't fire when the cursor enters/leaves the child elements -- this seems like behaviour you'd expect from mouseover/mouseout. And of course, what I'd ideally like is for the mouseenter/mouseleave events only to fire when I've left each section (which I've delineated using colours).

Here's the relevant fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ysim/yVfuK/4/

**Edit:** I tried giving the `.child-svg` elements a height and width, but that didn't seem to work either: http://jsfiddle.net/ysim/gMXuU/3

**Edit:** Here's the fiddle with the solution, fixed according to @pornel's suggestion: http://jsfiddle.net/ysim/HUHAQ/

Thanks!

Comment: What browser are you using? It seems to have the desired effect for me.

Comment: Read about event propagation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing

Comment: Is that really SVG-in-SVG rather than `<g>`?

Comment: @AlexMorrise: I tried it on Chrome, Firefox, and Safari... it didn't work on any of them. Which browser are you using?

Comment: @porneL: Yes, it's definitely SVG-in-SVG. I tried it with `<g>` and it seems that the `mouseenter` event handler is bound to each of its child elements, which isn't what I want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My guess is that `.child-svg` doesn't have any area on its own, so there is no way to hover it directly. When mouse leaves `<rect>` it leaves `.child-svg` too.

SVG doesn't have flow layout, so children *don't* affect size of parent element.

---

Here's solution: http://jsfiddle.net/gMXuU/4/

- add a `<rect>` with no fill as background
- add `pointer-events:all` to make invisible element "visible" to the mouse pointer

Comment: The `<svg>` elements are containers and have no clickable area themselves (this changes if they have a solid background, e.g using the `viewport-fill` property).

Comment: I had a bit simpler case... a DIV that displayed a child SVG. I had mouseenter, mouseleave, and click handlers for the DIV, but the SVG was causing unwanted mouseleave and mouseenter events on the DIV. After reading Kornel's answer I found that applying style `pointer-events: none` to the SVG prevented the unwanted behavior. IOW, the SVG no longer existed from mouse's perspective. Perfect! Thanks for the tip about `pointer-events` Kornel!

Comment: Thank you for this answer. `pointer-events` saved my ass. I had this weird bug where mouseleave is fired when the pointer is still on the element. This answer helped me found out this is because the container changes its `pointer-events` back and forth depending on scroll.